# Create a Delphi Class with external dll functions in it

Tags: delphi

I need to create a Class like this

```
unit Classname;
interface
type

     TSomeClass = class
     public
       member1  : SomeType;
       member2  : AnotherDataType;


       ....
       function SomeFunction: SomeType; stadcall;external 'ExternalDll.dll';

 end;
```

Can it be done?

How can I declare a external function (stored in a c dll) from a Class in Delphi

I'm using Delphi 7.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you want the external routine to be a member of a class? Normally they are global. Have a look at Windows.pas and check how `MessageBox etc` are imported.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is not possible at all. For such behavior, you'd need to load a separate instance of the library for each instance of the class, which in itself is not possible because calling `LoadLibrary` more than once from the same process to the same DLL re-uses the same instance.

Comment: Thanks for your answers

Comment: @jerry internal methods don't have one instance of code per object instance

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Right, but that's not what I meant. I'm not referring to instances of the methods, but instances of the overall class.

Comment: @jerry Which is what I refer to. Instance methods (code) are passed the instance (data) as a parameter.

Answer (score 3):

External functions cannot be part of a class declaration. You need to declare the external function with global scope and arrange that the class's methods then call that external function.

Comment: Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 2):

You could create a class with pseudo methods like this:

```
type
  TMyDllClass = class
  public
    NameOfDllEntryPoint: TFunctionTypeOfDllEntryPoint;
    constructor Create;
  end;

constructor TMyDllClass.Create;
begin
  inherited Create;
  LibHandle := LoadLibrary('path\to.dll');
  @NameOfDllEntryPoint := GetProcAddress(LibHandle, 'NameOfDllEntryPoint');
end;

MyDllClass := TMyDllClass.Create;
MyDllClass.NameOfDllEntryPoint(some, parameters);
```

This works fine, I have done it multiple times, e.g. for mitab.dll, libjpeg_turbo.dll and other dlls. The idea is to reduce cluttering the name space with global functions.

Note: For clarity I left out any error handling (e.g. if the DLL cannot be loaded or doesn't have the entry point). In this example this would result in an access violation because the NameOfDllEntryPoint field would not have been initialized.

Comment: Personally, I never ever ever ever put fields directly in the `public` section of a class. They should only be in the `private` section, and then wrapped by an actual function which in turn calls the function pointer. This ensures such class members remain read-only.

Comment: It also wouldn't even compile - fields must come before methods.

Comment: @JerryDodge: it works if you put them in a new public block.

Comment: @Rudy True, but not how this answer's written. Just pointing it out.

Comment: @JerryDodge I didn't try to compile that code. I didn't think it necessary, but have switched the order now. Regarding not having fields in the public section: Move the field to the private section and create a public readonly property that accesses it. Problem solved.